# Multiple choice question using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make multiple choice question, if user click the answer It'll change the color but the problem is when I change the  color, all the item change the color.

here's my code

```
const question = [
    {
        question: "lorem ipsum",
        choice: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    },
    {
        question: "lorem ipsum",
        choice: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    },
    {
        question: "lorem ipsum",
        choice: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    },
]

const App = () => {
    const [eachQuestion, setEachQuestion] = useState(question[0])
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    const handleChecked = () => {
        setChecked(true)
    }
    
    return (
        <h1>{eachQuestion.question}</h1>
        {eachQuestion.choice.map((val) => {
            return (
                <div onClick={handleChecked} style={{background: checked ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>
                    <p>{val}</p>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    )
}
```

How can I change color only for item I selected?

Comment: Maybe you want to store what value has been chosen (i.e. 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd') instead of a boolean, and then when iterating that choice will be checked when `valueChosen === val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const App = () => {
    const [eachQuestion, setEachQuestion] = useState(question[0])
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1)

    const handleChecked = (index) => {
        setSelected(index)
    }
    
    return (
        <h1>{eachQuestion.question}</h1>
        {eachQuestion.choice.map((val, index) => {
            return (
                <div onClick={() => handleChecked(index)} style={{background: index === selected ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>
                    <p>{val}</p>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one choice can be selected at a given time, you can store the choice as the `checked` state. Like so:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState()

const handleChecked = (choice) => {
        setChecked(choice)
    }
    
    return (
        <h1>{eachQuestion.question}</h1>
        {eachQuestion.choice.map((val) => {
            return (
                <div onClick={handleChecked} style={{background: checked === val ? 'red' : 'blue' }}>
                    <p>{val}</p>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    )
```